# How to remove script inside if condtion in jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation

I am working on one form where i am using external js script that works `onload`.
Now, I have to remove that script in my if condition.If user will select dropdown from form with `value == 1` then that external script should be remove else that file should work.
I am using below code :

```
if(value == '1')
    {

        var d =  $('script[src="include/javascript/gen_validatorv4.js"]').remove();     
        return false;
    }
```

its not working.

Comment: What is your HTML markup?

Comment: I dont get you can you please explain

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Why not use an Id attribute on that script tag and use that Id as the jQuery selector instead?

Comment: I don't fully understand why you want to remove it, once it's loaded, it doesn't hurt the performance to simply leave it loaded on the page.  In fact, it costs more in terms of page performance to run this logic and remove it.

Comment: @sadmicrowave in my some dropdown selections i dont want that validations and that external script is generic for all pages. so i cant remove that script from my header script.

Comment: @amitsutar, if you don't want validations on some items but you want validation on others, you should consider using classes to denote the items you want to validate, then in your `js` you simply initialize the validator on only those DOM elements with the necessary class.  The way you are going about doing this is a non-standard coding practice.  You should attempt the method I explained first.